# Fail to run mysql script for other user than root

Tags: mysql

I have mysql installed on ubuntu server. There is a mysql script that has a `select` statement in it. I want to output the result of this `select` into .csv file.

If I run the following command

```
mysql -u root -pTHIS_IS_PASS MY-SCHEMA < /home/me/script.sql
```

things work out beautifully. I, however, I run

```
mysql -u OTHER-USER -pTHIS_IS_PASS MY-SCHEMA < /home/me/script.sql
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 7: Access denied for user 'OTHER-USER'@'localhost' (using password YES)

I have no escaping characters in the password of `OTHER-USER`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: check the user's config to ensure they're enabled for access from localhost, and then check your username and password are correct. And also check they have the right privileges required to execute the query (i.e. access to the right databases,tables, commands etc)

Comment: @ADyson, did that, seems ok.

Comment: well we can't tell you if you used the right username and password or not. But if you share the user's setup and privileges we could at least help you to confirm if that's ok. If you're 100% certain that setup is ok then it must be a password problem, which we can't help you with

Comment: @ADyson, thanks for your time. It turns out I needed to grant `FILE` permission to the `OTHER-USER`.

Comment: @DimaDz, you should add your solution as an answer to your own question and accept it. This practice [has been explicitly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in StackOverflow. It might help other people in the future that might not even realize about the `FILE` permission.

Comment: @Lukman, yep, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the solution myself: I needed to grant `FILE` permission to the `OTHER-USER`.

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'OTHER-USER'@'localhost';
```

Don't forget that file permission is granted not to just one schema, but to the whole mysql.